# PHP: create file from an HEX string

Tags: php, string, file, hex

I have the content of a file represented as an Hex string and I want to re-create that file from that hex string. How can I do it?

**Additional information**
The hex string is taken from firefox memory cache entries such as the one below:

```
about:cache-entry?client=HTTP&sb=1&key=http://www.google.co.uk/images/nav_logo40.png
```

I am processing the `<pre>` element from these entries to extract and concatenate the HEX values. So from the below data output line obtained from a cache entry:

```
00000000:  89  50  4e  47  0d  0a  1a  0a  00  00  00  0d  49  48  44  52  .PNG........IHDR
```

I am producing this

```
89504e470d0a1a0a0000000d49484452
```

I am repeating the same process for every line so that I end up with 1 big string containing all hex values concatenated.

Comment: Expand your question. What has been "hexed"? Are you talking about encoding of binary values of the file or something else?

Comment: please see **Additional information**

Comment: You can use [this little script](https://gist.github.com/zxcmehran/b4cab69b70166187f5cb) for extracting cache entries of firefox and chrome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`pack`](http://php.net/pack):

```
file_put_contents($filename, pack('H*', $hex));
```

That will turn a string of octets in hexadecimal notation into binary:

```
var_dump(pack('H*', '313233'));  // string(3) "123"
```

Comment: I tested your method but it doesn't work. Could you please re-assess my question taking into account what I added into **Additional information**?

Comment: Indeed it does. My mistake. My script wasn't getting the hex output properly. All fixed now :)