# PHP: Show JPG from Binary

Tags: php, image, binary, jpeg, blob

I have a jpg blob thats been stored in an external DB and I'm looking to display that as an image via php. The issue is whenever I set the `Content-Type` to `image/jpeg` and echo out the blob I get the broken image icon when browsing to it.

I have tried making the file from scratch via sublime and that works when I save it as a hexadecimal file so I know the data is valid.

I have tried making the script create a file but it sets the `charset=us-ascii` so it won't get seen as a image file.

Does anyone have any experience with raw image binary files? anyone know how I can display the image or even save it out to a file?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I would provide the binary but its just too big to put on here.

EDIT: (added some code)

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg;');

$data = 'some long string of hex';


// tried echoing it directly..
echo $data;

// and writing to a file...
file_put_contents('test.jpg', $data);
?>
```

Comment: @Dagon Done... Not sure how much help that is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After continuing research I found this post [PHP: create file from an HEX string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5662779/php-create-file-from-an-hex-string)

With the following code I fixed the issue.

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg;');

$data = 'The hex data';

$data = pack('H*',$data);

$im = imagecreatefromstring($data);

imagejpeg($im);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `$im = imagecreatefromstring($data);`  The output it by `imagejpeg($im);`

Comment: You likely need to convert the binary string to a char string using a function like `$data = unpack('H',$data);` prior to creating the image.